# Ubuntu Studio not using USB soundcard (Focusrite 2i4)

Tags: usb, soundcard

Am now using a Dell Lattitude 7270, i7 processor 16Gb ram.
Am trying to setup Ubuntu Studio but I cant seem to get the OS to use my Focusrite USB soundcard. In a terminal I get;
steve@E7270:~$ lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:81b6 Dell Computer Corp. DW5811e Snapdragon™ X7 LTE  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:aa14 Seagate RSS LLC Basic  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 03eb:8453 Atmel Corp. Atmel maXTouch Digitizer  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5805 Broadcom Corp. 5880  
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 2717:ff40 Xiaomi Inc. Mi/Redmi series (MTP)  
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:3016 Dell Computer Corp. Optical 5-Button Wheel Mouse  
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1235:8200 Focusrite-Novation   
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0606 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Hub / D-Link DUB-H4 USB 2.0 Hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have edited /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and changed;
options snd-usb-audio index=-0
to
options snd-usb-audio index=-1

This used to work on my PC but this laptop is not reacting the same way. Have now disabled the onboard sound in the bios, rebooted but no joy.. In /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf I have noticed new (to me) lines above;

```
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388  
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard  
options snd-pcsp index=-2  
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard  
options snd-usb-audio index=-1
```

and am wondering if it is these I need to change the value of? Have tried a search on the net for these lines but have found no explanation for them..

Any ideas folks?

Comment: You've not provided any release details; and mention it working on one device but not another. Were they both running the same release? and using the same kernel stack?  (Ubuntu LTS releases offer two stack choices; with Ubuntu Studio that's chosen by the ISO install is performed with, but can be changed post-install; but you gave no specifics)

Comment: Apologies..  Am using 20.04.3 LTS Focal Fossa (Xfce Desktop) now. Before, I had a big desktop PC, quite a diferent beast. Are the different releases using alternate ways of installing a usb soundcard?

Comment: Sorted.. It was the USB hub I was using..!! Had been given it and was told it was a high speed hub, it was not. When I plugged the Focurite into a USB 3 port directly, Ubuntu Studio found it and it now works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the USB port that you connect the USB sound card to. It should preferably be plugged in directly to a USB 3 port and not connected via a USB hub.